# AWS step function costing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Right now I have one step function waiting on callback for TaskToken step.
So my question is will it incur cost if my callback step is waiting and not doing any work.
I believe its in Pause State but still wants to confirm if there will be no charge for step function that is waiting on callback step.
Asking here as my support plan is not active on aws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. As of **2021/05/01**, you will not be charged while your step function is waiting on callback from an assigned task. Many AWS services like lambda charge you based on usage time, however step function only charges you based on the number of state transitions your application requires.

You can also look here:[1](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/).

This is also inline with my personal experience of using step function. But the policy may be changed by time.

Comment: Does this apply for the wait state too? I’m planning to use wait state to wait for upto 7 days. Would this incur a huge cost?

Answer (score 2):

You will be charged for 4 transitions when using wait, independently from the wait duration.

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/06/19/step-functions.html